# How to create a custom mosaic with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a custom mosaic with flex that would look like this:

[image]

All the boxes have a width of third of the parent container except box 4 that is doubled in height and width.

I managed to get to the following condition:

```css
#push-group-element ul,
#push-group-element ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mosaic-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.mosaic-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.mosaic-item {
  height: 150px;
}
#push-group-element .mosaic-item:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 1 0 66.6%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="push-group-element" style="width:600px">
  <ul class="mosaic-container">
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="1">1</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="2">2</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="3">3</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-big" data-item="4">4</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="5">5</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="6">6</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="7">7</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="8">8</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="8">9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that box number 6 is not wrapping and falls to the next line, thus creating a new unwanted row with box 9 and a hollow space where 6 is supposed to be.

To sum it up:
How do I make box 6 wrap below number 5 and 7 8 9 are in the same row according to the sketch I attached.
thankyou in advance

Comment: Can you modify your html ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Yes I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a span element like shown below:

```css
#push-group-element ul,
#push-group-element ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mosaic-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mosaic-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.mosaic-item {
  height: 150px;
}

#push-group-element .mosaic-item:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 1 0 66.6%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="push-group-element" style="width:600px">
  <ul class="mosaic-container">
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="1">1</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="2">2</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="3">3</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-big" data-item="4">4</li>
    <span style="width: 33.3%;">
      <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="5">5</li>
      <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="6">6</li>
    </span>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="7">7</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="8">8</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="8">9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**OR**
Similar result using float property instead of flex(no need of changing HTML strucutre).

```css
#push-group-element ul,
#push-group-element ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

#push-group-element ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.mosaic-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red;
}

.mosaic-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.mosaic-item {
  height: 150px;
}

#push-group-element .mosaic-item:nth-child(4) {
  width: 66.6%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="push-group-element" style="width:600px">
  <ul class="mosaic-container">
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="1">1</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="2">2</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="3">3</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-big" data-item="4">4</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="5">5</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="6">6</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="7">7</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="8">8</li>
    <li class="mosaic-item item-small" data-item="8">9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need the span? Isn't there a way to accomplish it without it?

Comment: Flex container affects only its child elements and it is supposed to act as its doing in your case with your structure. By adding a span around 5th and 6th elements, I removed them from being the children of flex container and now they behave as normal div elements. Hence they wrap normally and you get the desired results.